# In Italy, can a party run for the elections with two different lists (in the same group)?

Tags: election, italy

Under the current law&rules, can an Italian party sign into the elections with two different lists, joined into one coalition, or is there a rule explicitly forbidding that?

(notice that lists are not automatically linked to a party, I'm just wondering if there are some special limitations when they are)

I'm not talking about running with two different lists in two different sections, I'm talking about having two lists **in the same section**, i.e. twice the symbol in the same ballot (obviously with some differences), such as "Party A - current X" + "Party A - current Y".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instruction of the presentation and admission of candidacy for 2018 National Election](https://dait.interno.gov.it/documenti/pubb_01_politiche_ed.2018.pdf) says at §1.4 (*Modalità per il deposito dei contrassegni presso il Ministero dell’interno - Methods for depositing mark at the Ministry of the Interior*) that **each political force** (i.e. party) **can provide only one symbol for each type of vote** (Senato, Camera, foreign district for Senato and for Camera).

> 4. In caso di contemporanea effettuazione delle elezioni della Camera, del Senato e della circoscrizione Estero, ogni forza politica può presentare un unico contrassegno per tutte le consultazioni o, in alternativa, può, al massimo, presentare fino a quattro contrassegni, purché:
>
> - un solo contrassegno per la camera,
> - un solo contrassegno per il senato,
> - un solo contrassegno per la circoscrizione estero - camera,
> - un solo contrassegno per la circoscrizione estero - senato.

Translated:

> 4. In the event of simultaneous elections for the Chamber, the Senate and the Foreign constituency, each political force can present a single mark for all consultations or, alternatively, it can, at the most, present up to four marks, provided that:
>
>    - a single card for the room,
>    - a single mark for the senate,
>    - only one badge for the foreign district - room,
>    - a single mark for the foreign district - senate.

The same document at §1.2. (*Caratteristiche del contrassegno di lista - Characteristics of the list mark*) **prohibits the presentation of marks identical (or similar)** to those used by other lists. So two lists cannot have marks with so little difference (e.g.: "*Party A - current X*" + "*Party A - current Y*").

In addition every list must provide the statute of the party or political association (or an equivalent document, details in the doc above at §2.1), but I do not know if the Ministry checks if two lists have the same statute.

Sometimes in Italy, coalitions provides fake lists (called [Liste Civetta](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_civetta)) used to drag additional votes to the coalition for mathematical scope (take some additional seats especially with old electoral laws) or confuse the elector with lists with ambiguous name.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible to have them registered under the same party.

In any case it should be possible to just add some dots to party's name and symbol and split it in a new *pokemo-* I mean party.

*Silly* parties have been conveniently created and used (mostly by right wing coalitions) to leverage confused people votes, like the [Retired people's party](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partito_Pensionati), which in great accordance to its name and stances, has received [state subsidies](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finanziamento_pubblico_ai_partiti) amounting to *[180 times](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partito_Pensionati#cite_ref-LaCasta_10-0)* real campaign spenditures and reached a peak of 374.343 voters in 2004 elections.

On the opposite side, during the previous elections we had THREE communists parties each not allied with the others.

So, depending on the context, the electoral system makes possible to create both fake cool-symbol parties to raises votes and infinitely small parties to make impossible for a given one to come back in parliament.